# How does Google calendar API works for webhooks quotas limits?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm looking to set up webhooks for Google Calendar API and I have a few questions regarding quotas and the approach I'm planning to take.

I want to configure a webhook to trigger only on calendar inserts for each user of my webapp, and then add a listener for each Google Calendar event. I have approximately 50 users, each with around 300 events to listen to. Is this the right approach, and are there any quota limitations I should be aware of?

I'm also considering using a single webhook that is triggered on all calendar modifications, but I'm concerned about the need to re-query the API to identify what has been changed, and how this approach might impact my quota limits.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know.  which i guess means, I have never heard other wise in ten years of working with this api.

Quotas are only imposed upon requests **you** make not the ones you receive. So i would assume that getting requests from the webhooks is not going to touch your quota.  Your quota will come into play when you make any requests to check on it again

Comment: Great, so set a webhook on each event is the best option, thanks !